# Is splitting http request header meaningful in golang http package?

Tags: http, go, http-headers

Most servers have the http request header length limit(4k~8k).
Usually we split the long headers into several parts.
For golang http package, I remember that it combines headers with the same key value into one giant header. Is this correct?

Like if I have a token which length exceeds the 8k limit. I'd like to split into several parts with the same header key Authorization.
Then send request using http package. 
Does this split make sense or not?

Comment: The [ReadMIMEHeader](https://godoc.org/net/textproto#Reader.ReadMIMEHeader) documentation describes how multiple headers and headers with continuation lines are handled.

Answer (score -3):

Hmm, I'm not sure that's quite valid. The `Headers` object is actually a map of string keys pointing to string slices.

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header

As such, if you try to set the same key it *will* be overwritten as per standard golang map functionality.

Comment: The net/http server appends to the slice. It does not replace the slice.

Comment: It's a map to *slice* of strings precisely to support repeated keys: https://play.golang.org/p/jdCBw2fIXHF.

Comment: Gah, sorry folks. :/